# Dropdown selection not auto-populating text box

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown box that currently has three different selections that can be made. Depending on what is selected, I want the Group ID that is associated with the group to auto populate in the textbox below. How can I get it so this does what I need?

Currently, whenever a selection is made, I get a `Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined` at the `var purchSelected = e.options[e.selectedIndex];` line in my javascript function.

SQL Query that populates the dropdown list:

```
$purchgroups = "SELECT [Purchasing_Group], [Purchasing_Group_ID]
        FROM Final_Structure
        GROUP BY [Purchasing_Group], [Purchasing_Group_ID]";
$purch = $dbh->query($purchgroups);
$purchDrop = $purch->fetchAll();
```

HTML for the dropdown and PHP foreach loop to bring in the values along with the textbox where the value should be auto populated:

```
<select class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all item2" name="purchgroup" id="purchgroup" onChange="updateinput();">

    <option class="choice"
        value="0" selected>
        Purchasing Group
    </option>

    <?php foreach($purchDrop as $dropdown) { ?>

       <option class="choice" 
           value="<?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'];?>" .                 
           data-purchgroupid="<?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group_ID'];?>">
       <?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'];?>
       </option>

   <?php } ?>
</select>

<label for="purchgroupid">Purchasing Group ID</label>
<input type="text" name="purchgroupid" id="purchgroupid" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="">
```

Javascript function that should be called on dropdown value change:

```
function updateinput() {
    var e = document.getElementById("purchgroup");
    var purchSelected = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
    console.log(purchSelected);

    document.getElementById("purchgroupid").value = purchSelected.dataset.purchgroupid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be an issue with how the `data-purchgroupid` values are being populated in the `<option>` elements. I tried to replicate your problem in the following CodePen, but I am receiving no errors:

https://codepen.io/justinthielman/pen/RqVERP

Use something like Google Chrome DevTools to closely inspect the option elements in your loaded HTML document. In Google Chrome, load the page, then right-click on the drop-down element and select 'Inspect'. If the `data-purchgroupid` is not what you expect, you will need to revisit your SQL query.

Comment: I still seem to be getting the same undefined error after making that change

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you are still having issues, would you mind sharing the live site URL?

Comment: I actually was just able to figure it out...i had a similar function that was grabbing the dropdown value already and it just needed a small tweak. I was making it a lot more difficult than it should have been. Thanks for helping!

Comment: No problem! Also, just a small thing that I missed, may have no effect, but you can remove the period (`.`) from the end of this line: `value="<?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'];?>" .   `